# Encrypt String with the Machine Key in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, cryptography, password-encryption, powershell-5.0

I want to Encrypt a password in Powershell to save it to a file. The `ConvertTo-SecureString` uses the current credentials to encrypt and decrypt the string.

I want to encrypt it with the local machine key (probably the SYSTEM account credentials) so every username on the same computer will be able to use the password.

I want the string to be undecryptable on other computers.

Comment: What is your use case? Preventing the password being visible in script files?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Nope. For that base64 is fine. I want to prevent from other people being able to use the password if they grab the file (through an SMB or NFS share that was open by mistake). Only users that have access to the specific computer should have access to the password.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the update. *not my downvote btw*

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers That's OK. Thanks :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's possible to use the `[Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Protect` function along with `[Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::LocalMachine` as the entity.

Code example:

```
Function Encrypt-WithMachineKey($s) {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security

    $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($s)
    $SecureStr = [Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Protect($bytes, $null, [Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::LocalMachine)
    $SecureStrBase64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($SecureStr)
    return $SecureStrBase64
}

Function Decrypt-WithMachineKey($s) {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security

    $SecureStr = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($s)
    $bytes = [Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Unprotect($SecureStr, $null, [Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::LocalMachine)
    $Password = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($bytes)
    return $Password
}
```

Comment: This is awesome! One question though: this "machine key", how long does it last? Is it like the AD Machine password that resets every 30 days? Or is it the primary certificate in the machine personal store? Or... something else?

Comment: It is created on the installation on windows and does not expire. You can replace if manually I guess, but it's not something that will happen automatically

Comment: Awesome, what about if `CurrentUser` is used instead of `LocalMachine`?

Comment: Okay found this, a bit old but informative: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/309408/how-to-troubleshoot-the-data-protection-api-dpapi
Also worth noting the risks of using DPAPI: https://www.harmj0y.net/blog/redteaming/operational-guidance-for-offensive-user-dpapi-abuse/